# Building an x64 project doesn't remember already built projects in F#

Tags: f#, build-process, x86, 64-bit

When I build an F# solution under x86 for a second or third time, projects which did not change are not built and it speeds up the building process significantly. When I try the same under x64, all the projects are built always even when they did not change. This makes the building process very slow as I have many projects in the solution.

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a little bit of search I have found why this happens.

I used to reference a COM of a program called Matlab. In fact it referenced mlapp.tlb and on build it compiled it into a dll. An interesting thing is that for x86 it works just fine and it does not force all the projects to rebuild when nothing has changed but using x64, it forces all the projects to rebuild even when nothing has changed...

The solution is to compile the tlb into a dll on our own using TlbImp.exe and reference the dll instead. But I wonder, is it not a bug??

EDIT: It is a bug:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/655035/tlb-com-reference-in-f-on-x64

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you haven't switched on "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" in Visual Studio's "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Projects and Solutions" -> "Build and Run".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, it does not help. I guess there is something wrong in the project settings (fsproj, sln etc.), because when I create a completely new solution it works as expected.